# SharePoint 2010 Ribbon on Application pages

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ribbon-control, applicationpage

I'm trying to create a SharePoint 2010 application page (AKA layout page) to display some information and allow users to perform some custom functionality.

I need to display custom ribbon tab for the functionality that I want to perform. And I want this custom tab to be displayed on the application page that I've created.

I've managed to create a custom ribbon tab and display it on list view ribbon through a SP feature. But how can I register this custom ribbon tab so that I will display on the application page that I've created?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're looking for *RibbonLayoutsPage* class from **Ribbon Utils for SharePoint 2010**.

http://spribbon.codeplex.com

Comment: By the way, this is everything i have ever wanted, and it finaly took us 2 weeks worth of work to get what 20 lines of code here allos us to do!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is the custom application page in the _layouts folder and extends from LayoutsPageBase?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460194.aspx

CustomActions have four possible RegistrationTypes

- List
- ContentType
- ProgId
- FileType

An application page has no List or ContentType, I dont think it is a ProgId (like infopath), that just leaves FileType. I have tried RegistrationType=FileType with RegistrationId=aspx but that doesn't work.

I'm just trying to think if i have ever seen an application page with ribbon buttons, but can't remember any. So I'm thinking it is not possible.

The ribbon definition does seem to have any either.

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\CMDUI.XML
```